# How to detect if the user clicked the X button in the leave event of a text box

Tags: c#, winforms, events, formclosing

I have a Leave Event for a TextEditor in which I perform a validation that an entry is required and display an error message. 
Before I perform the validation, I check if the form is disposing, or the Cancel button was clicked. In that case I exit the leave event.
But if the user clicks the X button, these two checks do not capture that and the error message is displayed. I do not want the error message to display if the user clicks the X button. How can I achieve that?

```
private void TitleTextEditor_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  UltraTextEditor _currentControl = sender as UltraTextEditor;
  if (this.CancelUButton.Focused || this.Disposing)
  {
    return;
  }
  if (_currentControl.Text.IsNullOrStringEmpty())
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Title is required.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a cruddy problem if you want to suppress the validation error message you display.  The only decent way to get ahead of it is by detecting the WM_CLOSE message *before* the Winforms code sees it and generates the Validating event on the control with the focus.

Paste this code to solve your problem:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        // Prevent validation on close:
        if (m.Msg == 0x10) this.AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

*Do* consider that you are yelling too loud.  The ErrorProvider component is a very decent way to display validation errors and be subtle about it.  And nothing drastic goes wrong when the form validates itself on closure, you only have to do this:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will use it and let you know how it turned out.

Comment: As for the error message display, that was a user requirement so we had to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

In the `FormClosingEventArgs` you have a `CloseReason` property, you can probably use it.

Comment: I  need a check in the leave event of the texteditor. By the time the control is in the FormClosing event, it is too late. But thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

How to find out if a control's Form has closed or not.  I have listened to the VisibleChanged event in order to divine the Form because ParentChanged can happen before the control is added to a Form (e.g. if it is in a Panel).  You might also want to unsubscribe from VisibleChanged events after the first one.

```
        //put this at class level
        bool _parentClosed;
        //put this in controls constructor
        //when control first becomes visible
        this.VisibleChanged += (s1, a1) =>
        {
            //find parent Form (not the same as Parent)
            Form form = this.FindForm();

            //If we are on a Form
            if (form != null)
                //subscribe to it's closing event
                form.Closing += (s2, a2) => { _parentClosed = true; };
            else
                throw new Exception("How did we become visible without being on a Form?");
        };
```

Comment: I am not sure how this will help my issue.